# How can I remove subdomain when the user accessed to www.xxxxxxxxxx.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Now in my app, the user can access to both `www.xxxxxxxxxx.com` and `xxxxxxxxxx.com`
but I don't want to use `www.xxxxxxxxxx.com`
How can I make the user redirect to `xxxxxxxxxx.com`?

My routing is like this

**routes.rb**

```
constraints(:subdomain => /^(|www)$/) do
    root :to => "top#index" 
end
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this in Rails rather than in your web server configuration? I usually use Apache for this type of stuff: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll just use apache then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, doing this in the web server is better, however if you are unable to edit your virtual host configuration, you can create a filter like the following in the ApplicationController:

```
  def strip_www
    if request.env["HTTP_HOST"] == "www.url.com"
      redirect_to "http://url.com#{request.request_uri}"
    end
  end
```